# Not constructive, really?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, moderation

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19901/cheaper-alternatives-to-dropbox-for-around-10gb

What am I missing? I asked a very specific question: alternatives to dropbox for a specific price point and minimum requirements. Was the problem that I mentioned Dropbox at all? How should I have phrased this question more appropriately?

(Note that I originally posted on superuser - to me services like DropBox are primarily desktop tools.)

Answer (score 5):

Basically it's a shopping request.

Two reasons:

1. You have a specific price point in mind
2. You are looking for an alternative to what you're currently using

Those two weigh heavily against the survival of your question as that [type of question doesn't fit the Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

A better version would be a question asking about how to fix or get around a limitation. Answers that offer alternatives would be okay, but the primary goal is to get a solid answer, not a shopping list.

Comment: Ok, so to make sure I've understood: there is a very specific kind of question which is prohibited for a very specific reason, and it even has a specific name ("shopping request") - but instead my question got closed for a totally different reason ("not constructive").

Incidentally, reading between the lines, if I hadn't mentioned a dollar figure, or indeed if I was only interested in free products, there wouldn't have been a problem. That strikes me as odd.

Comment: Incidentally, and somewhat amusingly, the "no shopping recommendations" rule only applies to superuser - which is not where my question was closed.

Comment: Take out the dollar amount and you'll still have a shopping request. @ste

Comment: The "no shopping recommendation" rule is not just Super User only. You'll need to point out where it states that it is that site limited. @ste

Comment: @SteveBennett The "No shopping recommendation" rule was introduced **because** of Super User, but applies to **all** sites - including Stack Overflow and here.

Comment: Ok, it's mentioned in the SuperUser FAQ, but not in the webapps one. I drew (apparently erroneous) conclusions.